# Passing pipe | and caret ^ chars through batch CALL

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to pass through caret chars through batch.
Escaping them once would be easy, but I need to do it twice.
I have an executable that will back up tables based on a Regex expression (not my code).
I want to back up all tables with an exclusion list.
Using `^(?!tableName$).*` works for a single table.

Batch File 1 (called from command line)

```
SET ignoreTables=tableName
:: Call the backup script
CALL SecondBatch.bat %ignoreTables%
```

Batch File 2

```
:: Passthrough ignoreTables
Executable.exe --ignoreTablesPattern="^(?!%1$).*"
```

But I'd like to ignore multiple tables. In Regex this means using the | (pipe) character eg; `tableOne|tableTwo` would require;

`SET ignoreTables=tableOne^|tableTwo`

Which is correct at the `SET` but not when passed to the `CALL`

The correct output that works from the command line is;

```
Executable.exe --ignoreTablesPattern="^(?!tableOne|tableTwo$).*"
```

How can I get this result out of the batch file?

Comment: Note: I would also be happy if I could use ^table to match all tables starting with "table" but then I have the same problem trying to escape the ^ caret to get it out of the first batch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In batch file 1 use:

```
SET "ignoreTables=tableOne|tableTwo"
:: Call the backup script
CALL SecondBatch.bat "%ignoreTables%"
```

And in batch file 2 use:

```
:: Passthrough ignoreTables
Executable.exe --ignoreTablesPattern="^(?!%~1).*$"
```

Run in a command prompt window `cmd /?` and read the output help pages, especially the last paragraph on last help page which is about when surrounding a directory/file name or parameter string with double quotes is required.

The first line of batch file 1 contains the command **SET** with the parameter string `variable=value`. By enclosing this parameter string in double quotes the pipe character is not interpreted anymore as operator. For more details about using double quotes on assigning a string to an environment variable see answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

The value of the environment variable is passed next expanded as first parameter to batch file 2. Again surrounding double quotes are needed to pass the string containing `|` as literal string to the second batch file.

In the second batch file it is necessary to reference the first argument without surrounding quotes. Therefore `%~1` is used now instead of `%1` as explained in help of command **CALL** output on running in a command prompt window `call /?`.

BTW: I'm quite sure `$` should be at end of the regular expression and not inside the negative lookahead.

Comment: Thanks Mofi. I had tried quotations, but not around the whole SET. I knew it would be possible somehow. It looks easy once you know how.